# Get row, if ID is not in Array/comma-seperated-list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have no idea if this is a SQL functionality or not... In short: I want rows from a table which id can't be found in a array/comma-seperated-list in another table. More info below:

The setup is two tables; a user-table and a questions-table. The user-table has a column called answeredQuestions, a comma-seperated list, which contains the questions-ids the user has answered.

I am trying to get 4 random questions, where each one hasn't been answered yet.

**How I get 4 random with SQL query**

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id >= RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM questions) LIMIT 4
```

But this will just return 4 random questions, without concidering wether or not the user has had that question before.

**If I should do it in Javascript, it would look like this**

```
var questions = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
var answeredQuestions = [3,5,9,12];
var sqlReturn = [];

for (var i=0;i<4;i++) { 
  var randNo = 0;

  while (randNo == 0 || sqlReturn.indexOf(randNo) > -1 || answeredQuestions.indexOf(randNo) > -1) {
    randNo = Math.floor((Math.random()*questions.length)+1);
  }

  sqlReturn[i] = randNo;
}

document.write(sqlReturn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't really like your solution.  You are making things a lot harder for yourself with your underlying database design.

You have two tables, one representing users and another representing questions.  What you really need is a table linking the two concepts, something like user-questions.

Suggested design:-

```
create table `user-questions`
(
   user_id int,
   question_id int,
   answered datetime
)
```

Suggested approach for recording answers.

Every time your user answers a question, whack a row into user-questions to signify the fact that a user has answered the question.

Under this structure, solving your specific problem, finding questions that haven't been answered yet, becomes trivial.

```
-- Find a question that hasn't been answered by user id 22.
SELECT
  q.* 
FROM 
  `questions`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `user-questions` uq
ON q.question_id = uq.question_id
-- Just a sample user ID
AND uq.user_id = 22
WHERE
  uq.question_id IS NULL
```

I don't play day to day with MySQL, so please feel free to correct any typos, SO'ers.  The approach is sound, though.

Comment: This was the type of answer I was looking for. I am, as you can see, totally new to databases and SQL... Thanks! :-)

Comment: No probs, we were all new to DBs once.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. I have set it up in SQLfiddle, where I have `inserted` a row in the `userQuestions` table for user 123 on question 1. But it doesn't return any question. It should `return` the other question not answered. See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16e64/4 ... can you see what the problem is?

Comment: Try this fiddle.  You were joining on questionid from the sub table.  needed to be id from question and questionid from userQuestions http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16e64/15

Answer (score 0):

While Paul is correct, you really should refactor your DB. The following should do it with your existing structure:

DECLARE @askedIDs VARCHAR(2000)

SET @askedIDs = (SELECT answeredQuestions FROM User WHERE UserID = @userID)

EXECUTE ('SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE ID NOT IN ( ' + @askedIDs +')')

Comment: Hi Dave. Thank you for your answer. I am new to SQL, and I don't really understand how to do what you tell me. Can you be more precise?

Answer (score 0):

The function `FIND_IN_SET` will help you to do so

To get all unanswered questions for a given user:

```
SELECT *
  FROM questions
 WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET( id, ( SELECT answered_questions 
                                FROM users 
                               WHERE id = 1 ) )
```

and to get only 4 random unanswered questions:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM questions
   WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET( id, ( SELECT answered_questions 
                                  FROM users 
                                 WHERE id = 1 ) )
ORDER BY RAND()
   LIMIT 4
```

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3dad/7)

Although you get this running, you should have a look at normalization and a redesign of your table structure.